# Contains operator logic

Tags: powershell

```
PS U:\> $bookmark = $null    

PS U:\> $XPPS = "145024-9999"

PS U:\> $bookmark += ,("145024-9999",0100,$false)

PS U:\> $bookmark -contains $XPPS
False
```

At first I was confused, but then I ran these commands:

```
PS U:\> $bookmark -contains 100
False

PS U:\> $bookmark -contains $false
False
```

Now I'm certain I'm missing some fundamental concept with `-contains`, whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "comma operator" `,` creates an outer array, so the contains-operator behaves exactly like it should.

```
$XPPS = "145024-9999"
$bookmark = $null
$bookmark += ,("145024-9999",0100,$false)

$bookmark.Count
1

$bookmark[0].Count
3
```

Do you see the problem? `$bookmark` isn't `ARRAY("145024-9999",0100,$false)`   but rather `ARRAY(ARRAY("145024-9999",0100,$false))`

```
$bookmark[0] -contains 100
True
```

Remove the array operator if you want bookmark to be a single-level array.

```
$XPPS = "145024-9999"
$bookmark = $null
$bookmark += ("145024-9999",0100,$false)
$bookmark -contains $XPPS

$bookmark -contains $XPPS
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Placing the unary `,` before an expression that evaluates to an array creates a *nested* array:

```
$bookmark += ,("145024-9999",0100,$false)
```

So, `$bookmark` is now an array containing a single item (that also happens to be an array):

```
PS C:\> $bookmark += ,("145024-9999",0100,$false)
PS C:\> $bookmark[0]
145024-9999
100
False
PS C:\> $bookmark[0][0]
145024-9999
PS C:\> $bookmark[0] -contains $false
True
```

Use the array subexpression operator (`@()`) instead:

```
PS C:\> $bookmark += @("145024-9999",0100,$false)
PS C:\> $bookmark -contains $false
True
```

Comment: Ahh, you where faster and explained it more detailed :D

Comment: @jisaak I've spent years training my StackExchange trigger finger(s) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you add another array into `$bookmark` with using `,(...)`

If you access it using `[0]` it works:

```
$bookmark[0] -contains $XPPS
True
```